# CakePhp 2.3: How to pass GET Parameters in router connect?

Tags: cakephp, redirect, router

I am about to catch links which are indexed in google and do produce a 404 as the site structure has changed.

This is the kink I can find in google:

> http://www.url.com/mp/text1/text2/city:57/page:3

What I want now is to send the browser to this address:

> http://www.url.com/mp/text1/text2?city=57&page:3

What I have so far

```
Router::connect('/mp/:text1/:text2/city::city/page::page', array('controller' => 'objekts', 'action' => 'search'), array(
    'city' => '[0-9]{1,3}',
    'page' => '[0-9]{1,3}'
));
```

But how could I attach the :city and :page as GET parameters?
Is that possible at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "attach" ?

Comment: Well, how do I transform the first url to the look of the second?